Join 3 tables with EF code first approach
There are jobs. you can post CVs for multiple jobs .Employer can accept or decline CVs
I have 3 models
public class Job
{

    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public List<CV> cv {get;set;}

}

public class CV
{

    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string CVPath{ get; set; }
    public List<Job> job {get;set;}
}

public class Status
{

    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string StatuNAme{ get; set; }  //Accepted or Decline

}

Joined Table should be as follows
public class JobCVStatus
{

    public int JobId{ get; set; }
    public int CVId{ get; set; }
    public int StatusId{ get; set; }

}

(or any suggestion)
How can i get the joined table as above in EF code first approach.
Joined Table should be as follows
public class JobCVStatus
{

    public int JobId{ get; set; }
    public int CVId{ get; set; }
    public int StatusId{ get; set; }

}

(or any suggestion)
How can i get the joined table as above in EF code first approach.

If you are need a JOIN table for JOBS CV and STATUS, in that case your entities should not be referencing each other like:
public class Job {

 public int Id{ get; set; }
 public string Title{ get; set; }
 public List<CV> cv {get;set;}
}

Job should not have object of CV because No relation between both the tables exists. Relation as in Foreign Key of JOB in CV.
Now about your issue, your entities should look like:
public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<JobCVStatus> JobCVStatuses { get; set; } = new List<JobCVStatus>();
}

public class CV
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CVPath { get; set; }
    public ICollection<JobCVStatus> JobCVStatuses { get; set; } = new List<JobCVStatus>();
}

public class Status
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StatusName { get; set; }  
    public ICollection<JobCVStatus> JobCVStatuses { get; set; } = new List<JobCVStatus>();
}

public class JobCVStatus
{
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public Job Job { get; set; }

    public int CVId { get; set; }
    public CV CV { get; set; }

    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}

if you dont want to navigate from status to JOBCVSTATUS in that case your STATUS entity would be same as you have defined.
Furthermore your you need to mention RELATIONS in your ApplicationDBContext class in onModelCreating Method which will look like:
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CV> CVs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JobCVStatus> JobCVStatuses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<JobCVStatus>()
            .HasKey(jcs => new { jcs.JobId, jcs.CVId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<JobCVStatus>()
            .HasOne(jcs => jcs.Job)
            .WithMany(j => j.JobCVStatuses)
            .HasForeignKey(jcs => jcs.JobId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<JobCVStatus>()
            .HasOne(jcs => jcs.CV)
            .WithMany(cv => cv.JobCVStatuses)
            .HasForeignKey(jcs => jcs.CVId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<JobCVStatus>()
            .HasOne(jcs => jcs.Status)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(jcs => jcs.StatusId);
    }
}

I hope this answers your query.

Job should not have object of CV. That's correct, but List<CV> already does that. The essential difference in your answer is that you use the explicit junction class in the collections, which, in general, is a better choice.
